# How do I reference another module in typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, typescript2.4

I'm having a problem with `import` and `module` in typescript 2.4.1.  I have two files:

testAdd.ts:

```
module mymodule {
    export class myClassAdd {
        static add(left: number, right: number): number {
            return left + right;
        }
    }
}
```

testCallAdd.ts:

```
//import 'someLibrary';

module mymodule {
    export class myClassCallAdd {
        static callAdd(): void {
            let result: number = mymodule.myClassAdd.add(3, 4); //error here
        }
    }
}
```

This code as it is now compiles fine.  I've found that if I try to import some library using the `import` keyword, I start to get errors.  In `testCallAdd.ts`, if I uncomment the import on the first line, I get an error that says **myClassAdd does not exist on type typeof mymodule**

I don't understand why I'm getting this error or how to fix it.  The `import` statement seems to be doing something to prevent the compiler from seeing `testAdd.ts`.  Can someone explain what went wrong and how to fix it?

This came about because I have an angular site that works fine, but I want to test it using jasmine.  I can't figure out how to set it up so that both the angular piece and the unit tests have access to the code.

Comment: @jpaugh, I included the error in bold in my question, "myClassAdd does not exist on type typeof mymodule"

Answer (score 1):

For your case you need to use the triple-slash directive: `/// <reference types="somelibrary" />`

See: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html

However, it would be best recommended to use module system, instead of namespace (which is what you are doing).

You can learn more about module and namespace here:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html

If you do intend to use namespace, since TypeScript 1.5 the syntax `module mymodule { ... }` is deprecated and replaced by `namespace mymodule { ... }`

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html
https://github.com/unional/typescript-guidelines/blob/master/pages/default/namespaces-and-modules.md

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) when I use `/// <reference lib="jasmine" />` I get an error that says "TS1084 invalid reference directive syntax".  (2) I'm confused by your comment "use module system, instead of namespace" with regards to your subsequent comment "the updated syntax is namespace mymodule".  It looks like you're saying "don't use a namespace, use a namespace instead".  Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, updated answer, see if it is more clear this way.

Comment: The `/// <ref` should be `/// <reference types="..." />`